# Im trying to create an ASP.NET table using a for loop for a set of hyperlinks

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have list of hyperlinks which i want to use to create a 2x* table (* is number of hyperlinks)

Here is my code...

```
for (int rows = 0; rows < hlist.Count; rows++) //Create rows for the number of                    hyperlinks, so i will always have a spare row.
{  
    TableRow row = new TableRow(); // Create the new rows
    table.Rows.Add(row); //Add rows to the table
    for (int cells = 0; cells < 2; cells++)
    {
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();

        for(int h = 0; h < hlist.Count; h++)                  
            cell.Controls.Add(hlist[h]);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
    }
}
```

All this does is list all my hyperlinks in a single column table, with a new row for each hyperlink!

Any help would be appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific on how you want the result to look like? An example would help a lot. What is the type of `hlist`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to create a table that shows two hyperlinks per row, you could try the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < hlist.Count; i += 2)
{
    TableRow row = new TableRow(); // Create the new rows
    table.Rows.Add(row);
    for (int j = i; j < Math.Min(i + 2, hlist.Count); j++)
    {
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Controls.Add(hlist[j]);
        row.Controls.Add(cell);
    }
}
```

However, using dynamically added controls in ASP.NET is complex if you want them to react on events. So I'd propose to check whether you could change your approach so that you can use a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. In order to do so, you'd first have to change your data model, e.g. to a list of Pair objects that contain two URLs, e.g.:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        IEnumerable<Uri> uris = GetUris();
        List<Tuple<Uri, Uri>> pairs = new List<Tuple<Uri, Uri>>();
        for  (int i = 0; i < uris.Count; i += 2)
        {
            var uri1 = uris[i];
            var uri2 = i + 1 < uris.Count ? uris[i + 1] : null;
            pairs.Add(new Tuple<Uri, Uri>(uri1, uri2));
        }
        rpt.DataSource = pairs;
        rpt.DataBind();
    }
}
```

If your URLs are not compatible with a Uri (maybe they contain a leading ~), you can also use strings instead of Uri.

The markup for your the Repeater would look similar to this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
         <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text="Link 1"
                   NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Item1") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text="Link 1" 
                   NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Item2") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
         </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```